# Как подключить wpf?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, зависимости

Не может найти сборку wpf, пишет: для сборки классических приложений для Windows требуется Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop. "UseWpf" и "UseWindowsForms" не поддерживаются текущим пакетом SDK.
Как подключить?

Comment: Вы проект как Wpf (.net core) создавали? Или какой изначальный тип приложения?

Comment: @Blackmeser не знаю, клонировал из репозитория, но вроде изначально wpf

Comment: Уточните, в Visual Studio Installer установлен ли флаг на "Разработка классических приложений"

Comment: @Blackmeser, да, установлено

Comment: А что за репозиторий может в нём ссылки битые или версии другие?

Comment: @Blackmeser, обновил студию, собралось, спасибо